# How to get % of equality between all the combinations of columns in a data frame containing factors?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, apply, purrr

Here's a toy dataset.

```
data = crossing(q = letters[1:4], nums = c(1:100))
set.seed(25)
data$val = sample(as.factor(c("x","y", "z")), nrow(data), prob = c(0.5,0.2,0.3), replace = T)
data = data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = q, values_from = val) %>%  select(-nums)


  a     b     c     d    
   <fct> <fct> <fct> <fct>
 1 x     z     x     x    
 2 z     x     x     y    
 3 x     z     x     y    
 4 y     x     x     y    
 5 x     x     x     x    
 6 y     z     y     z    
 7 z     x     x     x    
 8 x     z     x     z    
 9 x     y     z     y    
10 x     z     x     y
```

How to get mean for all the combinations of columns this way
There will be 6 combinations but what would be the smartest way in case there are over 5 columns to be compared.

```
data %>%
  summarise(mean(a == b),
         mean(a == c),
         mean(a == d)
         )

# A tibble: 1 x 3
  `mean(a == b)` `mean(a == c)` `mean(a == d)`
           <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1            0.4           0.41           0.39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(purrr)

cmbs <- combn(names(data), 2, FUN = list)
names(cmbs) <- map_chr(cmbs, paste, collapse = "_")
map_dbl(cmbs, ~ mean(exec(`==`, !!!data[.x])))

 a_b  a_c  a_d  b_c  b_d  c_d 
0.40 0.41 0.39 0.40 0.41 0.46
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you suggest a good place to learn more about the purrr library and apply family of functions?

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` version 1.0.0,

```
data %>% summarise(across(b:d, ~mean(.x == a)))
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   0.4  0.41  0.39
```

But I'm not sure what you mean about "5 columns": I see only 4.  So I may have misunderstood what you mean.

You can identify columns by position as well as name, so that may give you an easier way to generalise:

```
data %>% summarise(across(2:4, ~mean(.x == a)))
```

Comment: Hi, I was talking about a hypothetical scenario when I said 5 columns.
Also, your code just gives mean for all combinations involving "a" alone. Check out the solution given by @27ϕ9 where he got mean for all the combinations.